Optimal control version of Legendre condition from calculus of variations?
Let $F$ be twice-continuously differentiable and consider a calculus of variations problem of maximizing the functional
$$
\int_0^1 F(t,x,x')dt
$$
over the space of twice-continuously differentiable $x:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ subject to end-point conditions $x(0)=x_0$ and $x(1)=x_1$. The Legendre theorem then gives the following necessary contition for maximization: if an extremal $x^*$ is indeed the maximum, we must have:
$$
F_{x' x'}(t,x^*,x^{* \prime }) \leq 0
$$
for every $t\in (0,1)$. Intuitively, this corresponds to a second-order condition. It is derived by finding a perturbation of $x^*$ that would make the second variation of the functional positive if the above condition failed (which would constitute a strict improvement as the first variation has to be zero by Euler-Lagrange).
I was wondering if there exists a variant of this condition for optimal control problems. I know that the standard sufficiency results for optimal control rely on the concavity/convexity of the Hamiltonian, but I was looking for $a)$ a necessary condition for maximum and $b)$ one that depends on the convexity/convavity of the objective, and not the Hamiltonian.
Optimal control and calculus of varitions are closely related and the logic of the proof described above seems like it should go through for optimal control problems too?
